# Should I port my WebBroker projects to Indy

Tags: delphi

Long ago I started some "web applications" using Delphi 2007 and WebBroker (TWebModule).  At the time I assumed you needed a webserver such as Apache or Microsoft IIS in order to create any sort of website.  Additionally I don't use most of the Apache features (except for Virtual Server so I can have multiple domains on a single ip address and SSL).  So to me Apache is just an extra layer and makes makes debugging difficult.

Now enter Indy (TIdHTTPServer).  If I understand correctly, Indy IS a webserver.  So by using Indy I am no longer bound to use Apache or some other webserver.  Is this correct?

Will I have any issues supporting the Virtual Servers in an Indy environment?  And what about SSL.  I have searched the literature and from what I can see it fully supports SSL certificates.

I am now in the process of porting some of my application from WebBroker to Indy.  This mostly entails replacing within my code references of  **Request: TWebRequest** with **ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo** and references to **Response: TWebResponse** with **AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo**.

Is there anyway to use the **TWebModule** architecture within Indy so that I don't need to do all of this rewriting?

Lastly is there anything else I need to be concerned with?  My goal is to take Apache out of the loop.

Comment: Which version of Delphi?

Comment: @TOndrej Indy supports Delphi 5 (or 6) and newer ...

Comment: @mjn I was asking about version of Delphi because XE already has standalone WebBroker apps, using Indy, out of the box.

Comment: @TOndrej sorry, I didn't know (still using 2009), an easy option to remove Apache dependency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Indy's TidHTTPServer as a webserver, but it's much lower-level than IIS or Apache.  There is no concept of virtual servers - this you would have to implement yourself.

Indy does support SSL as well via the OpenSSL dll's.

I imagine the biggest concerns you will have will be security related...there are millions and millions of sites running Apache or IIS and there are a ton of people devoted to finding flaws in those platforms, with a bunch of people fixing some of those flaws as they come up.  Not so with Indy... there's one or two guys that respond on newsgroups to bugs that you discover. (One guy in particular, who will probably respond to your question here as well.)

Now, I use Indy HTTP server (along with SecureBlackBox SSL support) and I find it to be great for my purposes.

Comment: Also - the Web App Debugger uses Indy HTTP Server internally to run Web Broker datramodules...so you could model your server after the WAD utility in Delphi.

Comment: Of course, that makes Apache and IIS much, much bigger targets, so you also have lots more bad guys working on finding and developing exploits! The only way to make a server absolutely secure is to turn it off ;-)

Comment: I think that with an Indy HTTP server, scaling would be almost as bad a problem as the security one.

Comment: So you are saying Indy does not scale well?  Or at least not as well as WebBroker/Apache?

Comment: True about scaling be an issue, but a lot of that can be addressed with $$ -more hardware, more memory, load balancers, etc. Security cannot be easily purchased in this scenario.

Comment: As far as Indy scalability in comparison to Apache.. that would be a tough comparison.  Indy is a general purpose library with a HTTP server added on top.  Apache has been customized as a HTTP service for years so assumedly there are plenty of optimizations that you will not have in Indy.

Comment: Real numbers: I recently did get 1,000 SSL requests/minute (at 25KB ea) on my Indy server tested with JMeter with real transaction handling so it can handle a decent amount of load.

Comment: 1,000 SSL requests/minute is about 17/s or 420 KB/s bandwidth. Not much. And it depends on much clients at once and with how many connections, in keep alive mode or not. Even for static content, I call it slow. And IMHO speaking about Apache on Windows is far from optimal. Such not detailed benchmark data does not mean much.

Comment: Bandwidth isn't everything as you actually have to do something with the data being received. There's obvious time sitting waiting on the transaction processing - sql lookups, updates, inserts, etc.  20 client threads pumping JMeter load testing.  It's quite stable and fast enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Indy HTTP server calls the WinSock API, and is able to implement:

- A full HTTP/1.1 server;
- A full HTTPS server (using either OpenSSL libraries or other third parties, like SecureBlackBox).

AFAIK you can use Indy to publish web modules. 
See http://www.2p.cz/files/2p.cz/downloads/howto/indy_soap_web_services_in_delphi.pdf

You can also use other servers, for instance [directly the kernel-mode http.sys server](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/11/HTTP-server-using-fast-http.sys-kernel-mode-server), which is used by ISS and .Net WCF for instance, and known to be very stable and efficient (it bypasses the WinSock APIs). Of course, it will serve HTTPS conent, if needed. It is available in standard since Windows XP SP2, and therefore in Vista and Seven. Using this component will let Microsoft will do all the debugging work for you, and it will be updated with the host OS. I use it for instance in our Client-Server ORM, or directly to replace a deprecated DCOM connection, with very good speed and stability on customer side.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding virtual servers - the HTTP 1.1 spec requires clients to send a `Host` request header so virtual servers know which domain is being used specifically to handle the case when multiple domains have the same IP.  `TIdHTTPRequestInfo` has a `Host` property for that value.  In fact, `TIdHTTPServer` internally validates to makes sure that an HTTP 1.1 request has the `Host` header before firing any of its `OnCommand...` events.

Comment: Ahhh - then I handle virtual hosts simply using if..then statements depending on the host.